# how to generate a clrf in a string for each nn every 35 characters

Tags: xml, xslt

Suppose my message string length was about 140 (more than 35 characters anyway).
I need to split my string by using line feed.

Ex: the message length of 140

output required as :

- 1 to 35 chars in first line
- 36 t0 70 chars in second line
- 71 to 105 chars in third line
- 106 to 140 in fourth line

Can any one suggest me some logic for this?

Answer (score 1):

This is a recursive template that has configurable parameters for the length of the line and the character(s) to append to the end.

```
<xsl:template name="word-wrap">
   <xsl:param name="str"/>
   <xsl:param name="line-length" select="35"/>
   <xsl:param name="line-ending" select="'&#xA;'"/>

   <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="string-length($str)&gt;$line-length">

         <xsl:value-of select="substring($str,0,$line-length)"/>
         <xsl:value-of select="$line-ending"/>

         <xsl:call-template name="word-wrap">
            <xsl:with-param name="str" select="substring($str,$line-length)" />
            <xsl:with-param name="line-length" select="$line-length" />
            <xsl:with-param name="line-ending" select="$line-ending" />
         </xsl:call-template>

      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
         <xsl:value-of select="$str"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>

   </xsl:choose>

</xsl:template>
```

It can be invoked like this:

```
<xsl:call-template name="word-wrap">
  <xsl:with-param name="str" select="'Suppose my message string length was about 140 (more than 35 characters anyway). I need to split my string by using line feed.'"/>
</xsl:call-template>
```

and produces the following output:

```
Suppose my message string length w
as about 140 (more than 35 charact
ers anyway). I need to split my st
ring by using line feed.
```

***NOTE:** that this does not have any logic to account for word boundaries or hyphenation of words that are split.*

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just simply concatenating "\r\n" every 35 characters. Just use a loop counter that increases 35 each time as long as the counter is less than the length of the string and just use substrings and concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

There is an entry on Wikipedia that describes an algorithm:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_wrap

Answer (score 0):

With only fixed lines, you could hardcode it:

```
<xsl:template match="whatever">
  <xsl:value-of select="substring(.,1,35)" />
  <xsl:if test="string-length(.) &gt; 35"><xsl:value-of select="concat('&#10;',substring(.,36,70))" /></xsl:if>
  <xsl:if test="string-length(.) &gt; 70"><xsl:value-of select="concat('&#10;',substring(.,71,105))" /></xsl:if>
  <xsl:if test="string-length(.) &gt; 105"><xsl:value-of select="concat('&#10;',substring(.,106,140))" /></xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Admittedly crude, but effective.